# How to listen for a click even if the browser wasn't active

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm really hoping there is a way of doing this.

Standard behaviour is that if a button is clicked on a web page while the browser window was not the active window, that first click just makes the browser active. Only the second click is picked up on an event listener.

Is there a way to override this, so the even listener is triggered even on that first click? Either vanilla or using a library would be fine.

Comment: you could use a transparent modal like blocker to catch the clicks (make it disappear after the click)

Comment: I'm not sure what blocker is? But ATM a click isn't picked up even with a listener on the document, at least, with jquery $(document).on('click')

Comment: totally misread the question... (though it was the other way around). thats how the browser works... I dont think theres a code to do that... it either does or doesnt (testing here with chrome it clicks normally...).